# How to change Airplane Mode programmatically?

Tags: android, airplane-mode

I am following this 2 tutorial. [Tutorial 1](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/01/airplane-mode-onoff-in-android-with.html#.U_2lZsWSxKU) and [Tutorial 2](http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/turning-on-or-off-airplane-mode-programmatically-in-android/). But When i run thid project in my Moto G phone its unfortunately stop means after 17 api this is not working & give error

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE from pid=8675, uid=10233
```

I set permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<protected-broadcast android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE" />
```

I am also checking some solution like [Permission Link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml). I am getting still this error. So, how can i resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added this in manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`

Comment: Yes. i am also declare this permission. but i am still getting this error. @Dhruti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This broadcast can (now) only be sent by a system app, not by an installed app.

So unless you can get Motorola to sign your app as a system app, you are out of luck.

Comment: How can i sign my app as a system app?@zmarties

Comment: And when i only get current status of airplan on/off then it's gives correct answer. But not change. @zmarties

Comment: You can't in general (unless you are the phone manufacturer, or you run a custom ROM that you built)